# when i try to print data, error is appeared. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, list, typeerror

To calculate a genre distance between two movies, I made a list. Then, when user type a movie name find this movie in data

```
import math

data=[{"genre": "Action", "x": 12, "y": 2, "title": "DarkKnight"},
 {"genre": "Action", "x": 6, "y": 4, "title": "Inception"},
 {"genre": "Melo", "x": 2, "y": 4, "title": "BeforeSunRise"},
 {"genre": "Melo", "x": 1, "y": 8, "title": "HereToCome"},
 {"genre": "Melo", "x": 3, "y": 6, "title": "NottingHill"},
 {"genre": "Action", "x": 9, "y": 1, "title": "KillBill"}]


movie_title = input("Movie Name: ")

target = None

for movie in data:
    if movie['title'] == movie_title:
        target = movie
```

After then, I made a calc_distance() to calculate distance of 'target' and 'data'

```
def calc_distance(p1):
    distance = math.pow(target['x'] - p1['x'], 2) + math.pow(target['y'] - p1['y'], 2)
    return distance


data.sort (key = calc_distance)
data.pop(0)
print(data)
```

It works anyway. It shows in order close to 'target'. But when I try to print title only, it shows error.

```
print(data["title"])
```

print(data["title"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I don't know why it can't print title only. I made this list in dictionary for print a specific element first time. Help me, plz

Comment: `print(data['title'])` throws Exceptions because data is a list of dicts, therefore you need to specify the list index before accessing the dict key: `print(data[0]['title])` will print the title of the first movie in data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.pop(0)` does not *replace* the list with its first element, it just removes (and returns) it.

This is how you could replace the list with its first element:

```
data = data.pop(0)
print(data["title"])
```

Alternatively, if you want to print *all* titles except the first one:

```
data.pop(0)
print(*(element["title"] for element in data))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def calc_distance(p1):
    distance = math.pow(target['x'] - p1['x'], 2) + math.pow(target['y'] - p1['y'], 2)
    return distance

data=[{"genre": "Action", "x": 12, "y": 2, "title": "DarkKnight"},
 {"genre": "Action", "x": 6, "y": 4, "title": "Inception"},
 {"genre": "Melo", "x": 2, "y": 4, "title": "BeforeSunRise"},
 {"genre": "Melo", "x": 1, "y": 8, "title": "HereToCome"},
 {"genre": "Melo", "x": 3, "y": 6, "title": "NottingHill"},
 {"genre": "Action", "x": 9, "y": 1, "title": "KillBill"}]


movie_title = input("Movie Name: ")

target = None

for movie in data:
    if movie['title'] == movie_title:
        target = movie

data.sort (key = calc_distance)
data.pop(0)
data = data.pop(0)
print(data['title'])
```